# Dart - Converting a http response to a buffer

Tags: dart, http, dart-pub

how do i convert a http response to a buffer? im using the http pub package https://pub.dev/packages/http and one of the endpoints of an api im using is returning an image file, i want to convert it to a buffer. in JS i'd just do

```js
const result = await res.buffer();
```

but how do i do it in dart?

I tried a few different methods of the [Response](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response-class.html) class but couldnt get my head around it

Comment: What do you mean by "buffer"?  If you want the raw bytes as a `Uint8List`, there's [`Response.bodyBytes`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response/bodyBytes.html).

Comment: i didnt notice bodyBytes. tried it out now and it worked as how i wanted. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node describes [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer) as

> The `Buffer` class is a subclass of JavaScript's `Uint8Array` class

So it may safe assume that you can use the [`Response.bodyBytes`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response/bodyBytes.html) (which is a dart [`Uint8List`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-typed_data/Uint8List-class.html) type) field as `jamesdlin` suggested.

Comment: Ah yes that was what i was looking for. I shouldve checked the nodejs docs. didnt understand u8int. Thank u for this